# Flex data sent through POST into PHP not being sent to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, post, wamp

I am working on a flex application which consists of a form whose data is sent to a database on MySQL using PHP. The problem is the data sent through HttpService is not being added to the database. I am using WAMP on Windows 7 for the server and am testing through localhost on Firefox. I am using PHPMyAdmin to view what is on the database.

This is the flex code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function send_data():void
        {
            userRequest.send();
            this.currentState='thanks';
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="entry"/>
    <s:State name="thanks"/>
</s:states>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="http://localhost/index.php" method="POST">
        <s:request xmlns="">
            <FName>{rFName.text}</FName>
            <LName>{rLName.text}</LName>
            <Address>{rAddress.text}</Address>
            <Sal>{rSal.selectedItem}</Sal>
        </s:request>
    </s:HTTPService> 
</fx:Declarations>
<s:ComboBox includeIn="entry" x="150" y="150" id="rSal" prompt="Salutation?">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:String>Mrs.</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Miss</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Mr.</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Señora</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Señorita</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Señor</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:ComboBox>
<s:Label includeIn="entry" x="150" y="180" text="First Name"/>
<s:TextInput includeIn="entry" x="150" y="200" id="rFName"/>
<s:Label includeIn="entry" x="150" y="225"  text="Last Name"/>
<s:TextInput includeIn="entry" x="150" y="240"  id="rLName"/>
<s:Label includeIn="entry" x="150" y="265"  text="Address"/>
<s:TextInput includeIn="entry"  x="150" y="290" id="rAddress"/>
<s:Button includeIn="entry" x="150" y="310" label="Submit" click="send_data()"/>
<s:Label x="150" y="150" includeIn="thanks" text="Thank you for submitting the information"/>
</s:Application>
```

This is the PHP/MySQL side:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con->select_db("formdata"))
{
    $con->query("CREATE DATABASE formdata") or die('Could not create database' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$con->query("USE formdata") or die('Could not use');
$con->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id),Sal CHAR(20), FName CHAR(50), LName CHAR(50), Address CHAR(50))") or die('Could not create table');
$con->query("INSERT INTO info (Sal, FName, LName, Address) VALUES ('$_POST[Sal]','$_POST[FName]','$_POST[LName]','$_POST[Address]')") or die('Could not insert');
$id=$con->insert_id;
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1")  or die('Could not load');
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    echo $row['Sal'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['FName'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['LName'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['Address'];
    echo "<br>";
$con->close();
?>
```

This has worked when using an HTML form, but when switching to FLEX nothing happened. I have looked at other's code for Flex/PHP and what I have matches what they have, but mine does not work. Is the issue related to the Flex/PHP or is this a WAMP issue?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: **Warning!** Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent this.

Comment: This works fine. Are you getting any error?

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj When using the swf, no. When I try to open the index.php in localhost, MySQL says it can't find the $_POST['Bar'].

Comment: yep. It should show the error since when you open the .php file in the browser means you are not "POST"ing any value. Put your flex application in localhost and try running it.

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj I did, which is the reason for the question. Nothing is posted to the database. It's like the PHP file isn't even there.

Comment: Ok let me ask you this. when you type http://localhost or http://localhost/index.php what you are seeing on the browser?

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj When I type localhost I see the form, as if I ran application.swf.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with this for a couple of years or even longer and in mx so FLEX 3.5 or so but I vaguely remember that I had to include within my Php code sheet which used the FLEX Info to change into XML & then into the MySQL CB as it did not at all work just the strait way as you trying to do so!
I was thinking about it a couple of days ago myself to find it again and use it as my Apps where quiet complex, but also worked liked a charm. There is not much on the net not now nor ever before but if you get it it has a great many applications it can be used for! regards aktell

Comment: I just was going over your code above & saw this which maybe could be of some help! 
<mx:HTTPService url="http://localhost/cus....tails.php"
id="mainCustomerInfo" 
resultFormat="e4x"
method="POST"> resultFormat is NOT mentioned ???